# Why is my C# Singleton not working?

Tags: c#, winforms, singleton

Im new to .net and this is also my first post here so apologies in advance for any newb mistakes I may be doing:)

**Background of the problem.** 
I’m working on a C# project and as part of it I have to store windows form data onto a database. I am using a data class “person” to transport the windows form data to a class responsible for accessing the database on the windows forms behalf.  I wish to use the Singleton pattern on the windows forms code to prevent multiple instances of the window from existing.

**Problem**
In the save buttons event handling code I wish to create a “Person” object,  populate it with user entered values and send it to be saved onto the database. The problem occurs here. The “Person” object does not get populated!
I’ve tried doing this in another form where I have not modified the code to accommodate the singleton pattern and that works.

**So what am I doing wrong here? Is there a way for me to still keep the singleton pattern and make it work?**

**Window Form Code**

```
namespace AgTrain
{
    public partial class CreateAdmin : Form
    {
        private static CreateAdmin instance;

        private CreateAdmin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CreateAdmin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public static CreateAdmin getInstance()
        {
            if(instance==null)
            {
                instance = new CreateAdmin();
                instance.InitializeComponent();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public void makeInstanceNull()
        {
            instance = null;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person personToBeSaved = new Person();
            PersonDAO personDAO = new PersonDAO();


            personToBeSaved.FirstName = textBox1.Text;
            personToBeSaved.LastName = textBox2.Text;
            personToBeSaved.Address = textBox3.Text;
            personToBeSaved.TelNo = textBox4.Text;
            personToBeSaved.UserName = textBox5.Text;
            personToBeSaved.Password = textBox6.Text;
            personToBeSaved.UserType = "admin";

            personDAO.addPerson(personToBeSaved);           
        }

    }
}
```

**Caller Code**

```
private void createAdminToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateAdmin creAdmin = CreateAdmin.getInstance();
        creAdmin.Closed += (s, ex) => { creAdmin.makeInstanceNull(); };
        creAdmin.MdiParent=this;
        creAdmin.Show();
    }
```

Thanks.
Dumidu

Comment: You are calling `InitializeComponent` two times

Comment: I may be off topic, but in my opinion a form should never *ever* implement the singleton pattern! If you're not able to transfer data in and out of a form properly, that is a matter for a differnet question, but from the code you've posted I don't see the slightest reason for creating a singleton at all.

Answer (score 1):

In my opionion is thefiloe's solution the cleanest, but there is a further possibility to introduce (effective) singletons in C#:

```
public static readonly CreateAdmin Instance = new CreateAdmin();
```

Client Code:

```
CreateAdmin.Instance.DoSomething()
```

But as already mentioned I recommend thefiloe's way!

Comment: But can you use this pattern to create forms? Isn't there a requirement that this must happen on the UI thread?

Comment: Oops, I overlooked that the target class is a form. @CodesInChaos: You're right!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `InitializeComponent` twice. 
Try that:

```
private static CreateAdmin _instance;
public static CreateAdmin Instance
{
    get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new CreateAdmin()); }
}
```

Comment: Still getting use to properties. Thanks :)